# Scaffold's BottomSheet does not Respect Safe Area

Tags: flutter

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      bottomSheet: _buildBottomSheet(context),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(...)
```

The issue I got into is that the bottom sheet hides the lower part of the scroll view.  The expectation is that the body of the Scaffold (e.g., scroll view) would respect the bottom sheet. (My bottom sheet is a simple Container with a button).

I got this issue with Flutter web.

Comment: can you give the visual of your issue to give more context

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use SafeArea widget to solve your problem.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(...),
  bottomSheet: _buildBottomSheet(context),
  body: SafeArea(SingleChildScrollView(...)),
```

Answer (score 0):

The SafeArea widget only avoids system intrusions and not other elements of your app (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

Potentially you could achieve the desired effect by using the bottomNavigationBar instead of bottomSheet property of the Scaffold:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
              'Very Long Text Item $index',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => print('hit'), child: Text('Button')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have a solution though that uses the bottom sheet property? I’m interested to know why it doesn’t work.

Comment: I'm sure you can assign a GlobalKey to your bottomSheet widget, then use that to retrieve the height of that widget when building the body widget and add that height to the padding of the body widget, but the question becomes, why would you need to go to such lengths?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [SafeArea widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

SafeArea is a widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.
For example, this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.

In your case just try to wrap your parent widget with `safearea` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Set this property in your bottomsheet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
     useSafeArea: true, // Set this property true
     builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
);
```

Comment: showModalBottomSheet is not a persistant bottom sheet. Quoting the documentation: "A modal bottom sheet is an alternative to a menu or a dialog and prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the app."

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by placing a `SizedBox()` at the end of my `SingleChildScrollView's` child and give the

```
height: Height of the Container in _buildBottomSheet,

)
```

That's how my SingleChildScrollView's scroll shows the last item.

**Here is the complete code with your desired output.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home page'),
        ),
        bottomSheet: _buildBottomSheet(context),
        body: const SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data1'),
              Text('data Last'),

              /// Widget for generating space
              SizedBox(
                /// height must be greater of equals to the height of _buildBottomSheet
                height: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomSheet(context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Press'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```